# HttpOnly Cookie does not get sent with every request

Tags: kotlin, cors, fetch, vert.x, cookie-httponly

I have a Vertx based backend.
My base router gets the follwoing cors handler:

```
val corsHandler = CorsHandler.create().addOrigin("http://localhost:5173")

router.route().handler(
    corsHandler
        .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
        .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
        .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.PUT)
        .allowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE)
        .allowedHeader("Content-Type")
        .allowedHeader("Authorization")
        .allowedHeader("Cookie")
        .allowCredentials(true)
)
```

Let's simplify things and say I only have 2 endpoints. Lets call them auth and streamers.
When i send a post request to auth it validates the user and adds a httpOnly Cookie to the response the following way:

```
val cookie = Cookie.cookie("token", token)
     .setHttpOnly(true).setMaxAge(600_000).setDomain("localhost")
ctx.response().addCookie(cookie)
ctx.response().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK).setStatusMessage("Successfully authenticated!").end()
```

Where ctx is the RoutingContext.
I have these fetch requests:

```
export async function authenticateUser(user: UserRequest): Promise<Response> {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/auth/authenticate`, {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        body: JSON.stringify(user),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        credentials: "include"
    })
    return response
}

export async function getStreamersFromServer(): Promise<RawTwitchInfo[]> {
    const data = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/restApi/streamers`, {
        method: "GET",
        mode: "cors",
        credentials: "include",
    }).then((response: Response) => {
        if(response.ok) {
            return response.json() as unknown as RawTwitchInfo[]
        } else {
            console.log(response.statusText)
        }
    })
    return data
}
```

My problem is that after authenticating I can see that the cookie is set (on the network tab) and if i send another authentication request the cookie is present in the headers, however it does not get added to my streamers request.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the path does not match so the cookie does not get transferred.

Add `.setPath("/")` to the add cookie method - and this way the cookie will be sent across different routes